# Read node value from input xml file and write it on other output xml file

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing

I have an xml file which contains the following tag.

```
 <ClinicalDocument xmlns:ext="http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/Ci/Cda/Extensions/3.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
```

Now I have to read this and write the attribute value to a string.

Right now I am using the the follwoing code.

```
XmlDocument xDocument = new XmlDocument();
xDocument.Load(@"c:\Test.xml");
System.Text.StringBuilder ClinicalDocument = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
ClinicalDocument.Append("<ClinicalDocument xmlns:ext=" + xDocument.SelectSingleNode("/ClinicalDocument/@xmlns:ext").Value + " xmlns:xsi=" + xDocument.SelectSingleNode("/ClinicalDocument/@xmlns:xsi").Value + " xmlns=" + xDocument.SelectSingleNode("/ClinicalDocument/@xmlns").Value + ">");
Response.Write(ClinicalDocument);
```

But its throwing exception ***"Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function. "***

Please suggest what am I doing wrong or is there any other alternative. I am completely new to XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to get is not an ordinary attribute, it is namespace attribute. You can try using XPath `namespace` axis to get namespace attribute, something like this :

```
/*/namespace::ext
```

**working demo example :**

```
var xml = @"<ClinicalDocument xmlns:ext='http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/Ci/Cda/Extensions/3.0' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns='urn:hl7-org:v3'/>";
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var result = doc.SelectSingleNode("/*/namespace::ext");
Console.WriteLine(result.Value);
```

**<kbd>[`Dotnetfiddle Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/txAVV7)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/Ci/Cda/Extensions/3.0
```

Comment: Hey. Thanx. This was exactly what I was looking for.